# FFMpeg C Lib - Transpose causes corrupt image

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to set up a transcoding pipeline with ffmpeg C lib, but if I transpose it, the video is corrupted as shown below.

If I don't transpose, the video is fine, ie the rest of the pipeline is correctly set up.

I need to convert the AVFrame to another datatype to use it with other software. I believe the corruption happens on the copy, but I'm not sure why. Possible something to do with rotating YUV420P pixels?

[image: video is rotated but corrupted]

The constructor (code was taken [from here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/filtering__video_8c_source.html))

```
MyFilter::MyFilter(const std::string filter_desc, AVCodecContext *data_ctx){
  avfilter_register_all();
  buffersrc_ctx = NULL;
  buffersink_ctx = NULL;

    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();

  AVFilter *buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
  if (!buffersink) {
    throw error("filtering sink element not found\n");
  }

  if (avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out", NULL, NULL, filter_graph) < 0) {
    throw error("Cannot create buffer sink\n");
  }


filterInputs  = avfilter_inout_alloc();
  filterInputs->name       = av_strdup("out");
  filterInputs->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
  filterInputs->pad_idx    = 0;
  filterInputs->next       = NULL;

    AVFilter *buffersrc  = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    if (!buffersrc) {
        throw error("filtering source element not found\n");
    }

    char args[512];
    snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
                    data_ctx->width, data_ctx->height, data_ctx->pix_fmt,
                    data_ctx->time_base.num, data_ctx->time_base.den,
                    data_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num, data_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

    log(Info, "Setting filter input with %s", args);


    if (avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in", args, NULL, filter_graph) < 0) {
         throw error("Cannot create buffer source\n");
    }

    filterOutputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    filterOutputs->name       = av_strdup("in");
    filterOutputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    filterOutputs->pad_idx    = 0;
    filterOutputs->next       = NULL;

    if ((avfilter_graph_parse(filter_graph, filter_desc.c_str(), filterInputs, filterOutputs, NULL)) < 0)
            log(Warning,"Could not parse input filters");

    if ((avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL)) < 0)
        log(Warning,"Could not configure filter graph");

}
```

And the process

```
AVFrame * MyFilter::process(AVFrame *inFrame){

    if (av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(buffersrc_ctx, inFrame->get(), AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_PUSH | AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF ) < 0) {
         throw error("Error while feeding the filtergraph\n");
     }

    int i = 0;
    AVFrame* outFrame =  av_frame_alloc();
    if( av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, outFrame) < 0 ){
     throw error("Couldnt find a frame\n");
    }
  return outFrame;
}
```

And the filter I'm using is:

```
 std::string filter_desc = "transpose=cclock"
```

As an extra note, it seems like the top bar(visible in the screen capture above) is actually composed of properly rotated pixels, and this works for the whole video. It just degrades for the remaining 99% of pixels.

Using this works :
`std::string filter_desc = "rotate=PI/2"`, but then the resolution is not properly shifted. If I try 
`std::string filter_desc = "rotate='PI/2:ow=ih:oh=iw'"`
the same issue as before starts appearing again. It seems to be associated with the change in resolution.

I think the corruption might come from a copy thats made after (for compatibility with something else I'm using):

```
void copyToPicture(AVFrame const* avFrame, DataPicture* pic) {
    for (size_t comp=0; comp<pic->getNumPlanes(); ++comp) {
        auto const subsampling = comp == 0 ? 1 : 2;
        auto const bytePerPixel = pic->getFormat().format == YUYV422 ? 2 : 1;
        // std::cout<<"Pixel format is "<<pic->getFormat().format<<std::endl;
        auto src = avFrame->data[comp];
        auto const srcPitch = avFrame->linesize[comp];

        auto dst = pic->getPlane(comp);
        auto const dstPitch = pic->getPitch(comp);

        auto const w = avFrame->width * bytePerPixel / subsampling;
        auto const h = avFrame->height / subsampling;

        for (int y=0; y<h; ++y) {
            memcpy(dst, src, w);
            src += srcPitch;
            dst += dstPitch;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a completely unrelated issue, this code works!